# How to correctly fill a list of list in c++

Tags: c++, list, stl, std

Consider the following code:

```
#include <string>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    list<int> l{1,2,3,4};
    list<list<int>> ll;
    ll.push_back(l);
    return 0;
}
```

After the `push_back`, the `ll` list is containing one empty element.
I am wondering why it is not filled with the content of list `l`.

Note: I am on Mac OS 10.9 using Xcode 5.0.1.

#### Edit 1:

Here is the lldb output:

```
(lldb) p l
(std::__1::list<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >) $0 = size=4 {
  [0] = 1
  [1] = 2
  [2] = 3
  [3] = 4
}
(lldb) p ll
(std::__1::list<std::__1::list<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::list<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > > >) $1 = size=1 {
  [0] = size=0 {}
}
(lldb)
```

#### Edit 2

As @molbdnilo said, it looks like a debugger issue because when a new list initialized with the first item of `ll` I get the same content than in `l`.

Comment: Works for me on VC++12.  How are you testing?  Maybe you're debugging in release mode?

Comment: How do you know it's empty? ll contains 1 four-element list on my system (g++ 4.8)

Comment: Show us the code about how you find the contents of `ll`?

Comment: [Don't simply wonder](http://ideone.com/DYKDtZ) Show some code to prove your point

Comment: Looks like a debugger display problem; I get the same effect, but if I assign `*ll.begin()` to a new list, that list is the way it should be. So most likely an Apple bug.

Comment: @molbdnilo: you are right

Answer (score 1):

Hope this sample code helps to manipulate in list stl,

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
   list<int> l{1,2,3,4};
   list<int> l1{5,6,7,8};
   list<list<int>> ll;
   ll.push_back(l);
   ll.push_back(l1);
   list<list<int>>::iterator itr;
   for (itr=ll.begin(); itr != ll.end(); itr++)
   {
       list<int>tl=*itr;
       list<int>::iterator it;
       for (it=tl.begin(); it != tl.end(); it++)
       {
           cout<<*it;
       }
       cout<<endl<<"End"<<endl;
   }
   return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually will fill `ll` with the contents of list `l`. So if you continue it as follows:

```
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    std::list<int> l{1,2,3,4};
    std::list<std::list<int>> ll;
    ll.push_back(l);
    auto first_list = *(ll.begin());
    auto second_element_of_first_list = *(std::next(first_list.begin()));
    std::cout << second_element_of_first_list << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

This will print `2`. See it running on [<kbd>cpp.sh</kbd>](http://www.cpp.sh/6kfosh).